# Messenger GraphApi - Filter by "updated_time" field

Tags: facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-messenger, messenger

I'm trying to query the conversations and filter by update date. But the "updated_time" field doesn't seem to respect the filter rule.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2f2a.png)

I tried as follows, but now works:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yL0AN.png)

Can anyone solve this problem?

A filter template that works in the Messenger Graph API